# Open only one worksheet in a new window

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet

I'm trying to make a macro to open a hidden sheet on that workbook in a new Excel window, but I want only to open that sheet. I tried, but it opens all the sheets in a new window with the sheet I want activated.

It opened a new window with all the sheets, and I just want to open a new window with only that sheet.

Comment: Can you show us your attempt (code)?

Comment: Sub openwindowsheetvasilhame()


ActiveWindow.NewWindow


With Sheets("Vasilhame")
Sheets("Vasilhame").Activate
.Visible = True
End With


End Sub

Answer (score 1):

Try this.  The new workbook becomes the active WB.

```
Sub openwindowsheetvasilhame()
        With Sheets("Vasilhame")
                .Activate
                .Visible = True
                .Copy
                .Visible = False
        End With
End Sub
```